# Does using C# CLR have any advantages over C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr

I do some utility works to update databases which are simply gathering data from some websites and web services, and update related rows of database continously. I wrote an application on C# to do this. It is my bad, but I heard about using CLR for the first time today and googled it to make some research. I found many articles on comparing CLR with T-SQL but couldn't find much about difference between using CLR on SQL server and a normal application which connects to SQL server. Is it wise to use CLR on such utility occasions?

**Edit:**
To make the question more clear, I wonder about comparison between using C# inside SQL Server and using C# as a main application, querying SQL server.

Comment: The rule of thumb I'd use is use CLR when SQL Server is going to take responsibility in some way, shape, or form, for kicking off the code - whether that be because the CLR object is referenced in a query, or SQL Agent executes a stored procedure, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe an application that seems to be a webcrawler (or similar). That does not sound at all like a good fit for SQL CLR. Performance-wise, SQL CLR helps you by removing network roundtrips and network transfers, basically. The performance of a web crawler would not at all depend on the network latency to the database.

I think you should investigate general performance tuning techniques for SQL Server. Get your schema and indexes right. Use efficient queries. Don't be too chatty on the network.

I certainly would not want my SQL Server instance to issue HTTP requests to foreign web servers... That seems like a reliability killer and possibly a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit known to me of using `C#` like a core language for stored procedure on latest versions of `SQL Server`, is a

- can write more complex logic, as `C#` language permits that
- do not need to learn a new language (`SQL`)

Comment: But can you compare CLR and C# application? In both cases I need to use SQL, what I wonder is, is there any difference on performance.

Comment: @Kuzgun: you're question is not correct: CLR (Common Language Rntime) is a platform on which *programming languages* like C#, VB.NET, F#... run. If you mean compare performance of C# *inside* SQL Server like stored procedure against C# code that runs query from ordinary application, I don't think it's something that could be compared with good percentage of relevance, as one runs on the server, another runs on the client, so the *environments* of them  are completely different.

Comment: @Kuzgun: If you're asking what is better to use: C# Stored Procedure, or Query from app: stored procedure is usually better approach, as servers are usually have more power then user desktop and you can make calculations and aggregations *on the server*, so make them faster and *trasmit less data* on wire to the client, so also *deliver* result faster.

Comment: thanks for comments I edited the question. I meant using C# to create CLR project and compare it to a normal C# app querying SQL server. I have to use C# to gather data from web, thats why I cannot run a normal stored procedure.

Comment: @Kuzgun: saying *C# inside SQL Server* what do you mean precisely ?